# Font does not smooth on Opera

Tags: html, css

I am using "Play" font from Google fonts.

But for some reason Opera renders fonts not smooth.[image]

Is there any way to enable 'antialiasing' for all browsers ?

[Big image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZARk.png)

Comment: try taking a look at http://typerendering.com/ this has a library that does a lot of the detection and adds classes so you can do rendering  / smoothing via styles, when the browser can